# Seeking census religious data by block group in New Jersey?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, us-census, religion

Where can I find religious census block group data for New Jersey (NJ)?

I am fairly certain this data is on american factfinder but I am unable to find it.

My plan is to join to a NJ block group shapefile and display is on a map.

Comment: The U.S. Census Bureau does not collect religious identity data at the Census Block Group level. Barring that, I am unaware of any third-party which collects such information.

Comment: i agree with @Kotebiya. Such kind of data is highly private and would not be shared openly in such a fine resolution, due to potenial discrimination.